# Problem with the camera

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, camera

I am currently developing an app which is using the UIImagePickerController for taking pictures with the build in camera.

What I no want to do, is to provide the user a switch on bottom bar of the UIImagePickerController to be able to switch between the front and the rear camera (if available of course). I know how it's possible to determine if there's a front camera, but how can I show such a switch on the bottom bar?

Thanx for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

.h file
@property(nonatomic) UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice cameraDevice;

cameraButtonPressed method opens the rear camera. changeCam method toggles between rear and front camera.

.m file

```
-(void) cameraButtonPressed

{
 overLay=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)];

 UIImage *CameraClickImg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"capture.png"];
 UIButton *captureBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [captureBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(35,440, 240,40)];
 [captureBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(captureImage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [captureBtn setImage:CameraClickImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];



 UIButton *changeBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [changeBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(250,30, 40,40)];
 [changeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(changeCam) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [changeBtn setImage:CameraClickImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];


 picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
 picker.allowsEditing = NO;
 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
 picker.showsCameraControls=NO;
 picker.cameraFlashMode =  UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
 picker.cameraOverlayView=overLay;
 [self presentModalViewController: picker animated:YES];
 [overLay addSubview:captureBtn];
 [overLay addSubview:changeBtn];

 [picker release];

 [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];

}


-(void)captureImage
{

 [picker takePicture];


}


-(void)changeCam
{
 if (picker.cameraDevice==UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear) 
  picker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
 else
  picker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either set `showsCameraControls`of your `UIImagePickerController` to `YES` or provide your own controls with `cameraOverlayView`.

For switching between front and rear camera use the `cameraDevice` property of `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: Citation from the question: "...but how can I show such a switch..."

Comment: Citation from the question: "...able to switch between the front and the rear camera", so he means how he can show a switch **that shows the front-camera when it's switched on**.

Comment: @Nuker Please clarify your question.

Comment: What I want to have is the following: I want the UIImagePicker to have a switch on the bottom bar where the user can switch between the front and the rear camera when the UIImagePicker is shown. So, when the user presses a button "Take picture", I want to show him the common UIImagePicker and the user can choose within the UIImagePicker whether he wants to take a picture with the front or the rear camera. I hope this clarifies my question a bit.

Comment: @Nuker Do you want to know how to present the controls (which is described in my answer) or how to switch between front and rear camera within your own code?

Comment: Both. Because the UIImagePickerController doesn't provide any API to custom controls to it and I don't want to do it brute force so my app won't get certified by apple.

Comment: Thanks for that, but how can I add a switch to right side of the bottom bar in the UIImagePickerController?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: @Nuker it is possible to do what you want, you just need to create a custom switch or button to perform the toggle and add it as a subview to your custom cameraOverlayView.